# importing weka in java after installing weka

Tags: netbeans6.8, weka

i stalled weka in my system but still im having problem to use weka classes in my java code?

im using netbean its show me class file not available when i try to import my weka class?

Comment: Include weka jar files

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Adding_a_new_library_to_NetBeans ?

Answer (score 1):

The package view  of a weka test project :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Adding `weka.jar` into your Java project classpath.

2) Importing the class you want to load like this `import weka.XXX.XXX;`.

Make sure the above two simple steps is done. Any question :)